# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'IPython' on logging the R model

Tags: r, azure-databricks, mlflow, jupyterhub

For R model registration from jupyter to azure databricks, I was logging the  R model using mlflow,

```
predictor <- crate(function(x) predict(model,.x))
mlflow_log_model( predictor,'MODEL')< facing error here>
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/r-mlflow-1.26.1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mlflow/utils/databricks_utils.py", line 44, in _get_dbutils

import IPython

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'IPython'

Answer (score 0):

when I try to import IPython module using below code:

```
from IPython import get_ipython
```

I got below error:

[image]

I installed the IPython module using below command:

```
pip install ipython
```

[image]

I imported ipython module and run the below code:

```
import IPython
from IPython import get_ipython
from IPython.display import Image

print(Image)
print(IPython.__version__)
```

It executed successfully with out any error:

[image]